# Print out the key index number into the html using react

Tags: reactjs

I want to print out the list of numbers in my iteration, what am I doing wrong?

main.js component:

```
export class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <h1>car2go data</h1>
          {Car2go.placemarks.map((content, index) => {
            return <RenderTable content={content} key={index} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

renderTable.js component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class RenderTable extends Component {
  render() {
    const { content } = this.props;
    const { key } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <span>{key}</span>
          {content.address}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RenderTable;
```

I'm able to print the content. address values, for each iteration, but I want to number the list, that's why I put a span before this. I can even see the key attribute printing out the number in inspector mode, but I need that in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`key` in `react` has a special meaning and it is useful for listing and uniquely identifying the elements. Don't use `key` as a props unless it is used for unique listing.** [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Try to replace this,

```
<RenderTable content={content} key={index} />
```

with this,

```
<RenderTable content={content} ind={index} />
```

and use like this,

```
export class RenderTable extends Component {
  render() {
    const { content } = this.props;
    const { ind } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <span>{ind}</span>
          {content.address}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the **key** prop in component. But that **key** prop is just for react's internal use. So, that **key** was not included in **this.props** by default. Hence, you need to use some other prop name (other than 'key') to pass index.

So, please change this from

`<RenderTable content={content} key={index} />`

to

`<RenderTable content={content} key={index} num={index} />`

then you can use **num** like

```
export class RenderTable extends Component {
  render() {
    const { content } = this.props;
    const { num } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <span>{num}</span>
          {content.address}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.